# How to make a timestamp not show the time

Tags: mysql, database

Is there a way to simply change a field properties to to not show the time? I want it to just show the date.

My field name is "date". I am using mysql. It is type `TIMESTAMP`, and defaulted to current timestamp.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `DATE` type for your column instead of `TIMESTAMP` and set it to `NOW()` when you do an `INSERT`.

There's more about the differences between `DATE`, `DATETIME`, and `TIMESTAMP` here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html

Answer (score 1):

Just convert the datetime to a date.

`CONVERT(date, YourDateTime)`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you alter the schema to convert that column to a `DATE` column instead?

Also note that using [reserved keywords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) like *DATE* as column names is generally bad form.

Comment: Becuase DATE wont let me assign defualt Current timestamp to it.

Comment: You can always assign the current date to it.